# Linq query to sort collection

Tags: c#, linq

i have custom a collection `LoanOptionsProgramVersionList` which has bolean property `Configured`,string `Description` and `Code`.While insert and delete from the collection i want sort the collection in the below order. So one record inserted to database configured become yes. When deleted `Configured` become "No". So it Notify property.

1. sort by configured
2. then by description
3. then by code

i have tried the below code After insert.

```
IOrderedEnumerable<ProgramVersionRecord> orderedList =    
     LoanOptionsProgramVersionList
         .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProgramVersionConfigured == true);
```

Also below code for deletion

```
 IOrderedEnumerable<ProgramVersionRecord> orderedList =
      LoanOptionsProgramVersionList.OrderBy(p => p.Description);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand fully what you're asking, especially regarding the database(?) access. But if you want to order by multiple criteria, there's the [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) LINQ method. So you'd have something like `LoanOptionsProgramVersionList.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProgramVersionConfigured == true).ThenBy(p => p.Description).ThenBy(p => p.Code);`

Comment: Why not just use a sorted list and either implement IComparable in ProgramVersionRecord or pass in an IComparer to the constructor of the sorted list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ThenBy`

```
IOrderedEnumerable<ProgramVersionRecord> orderedList = LoanOptionsProgramVersionList
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProgramVersionConfigured) // configured has priority
    .ThenBy(p => p.Description)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Code);
```

Answer (score 1):

When ordering by `ProgramVersionConfigured` property use this property instead of result of comparison with boolean. Also use `ThenBy` to add another sorting:

```
 LoanOptionsProgramVersionList.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProgramVersionConfigured)
                              .ThenBy(p => p.Description)
                              .ThenBy(p => p.Code)
```

Comment: I think the `OrderByDescending` was correct, at least it means that configured programs have the highest priority(i rememeber this trick in this way: `true=1` and `false=0`).

Comment: Agree with you. And +1 for beating me by 10 seconds :)